# Vuetify adding button next to datatable data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I put a button in the marked place?

[There is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlvMF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71162907-92xs69?file=/src/components/AppendButton.vue

You can use the `item` slot and customize it to your needs.

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-key="name"
    class="elevation-1"
>
    <template #item.calories="{item}">
        {{ item.calories }} <v-btn v-if="item.name=='Frozen Yogurt'" class="ml-1" small outlined>B</v-btn>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

[image: Demo]